# Vectorizing Arithmetic Operations

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I am trying to improve the performance of my code by converting some iterations into matrix operations in Matlab. One of these is the following code and I need to figure out how can I avoid using loop in the operation.

Here gamma_ic & bow are two dimensional matrices.
c & z are variables set from outer iterations.

```
for z=1:maxNumber,
    for c=1:K,
        n = 0;
        for y2=1:number_documents,
            n = n+(gamma_ic(y2,c)*bow(y2,z));
        end
        mu(z,c) = n / 2.3;
    end
end
```

Appreciate your assistance.

Edit. Added The loop for c and z. The iteration goes on till the maximum indices in gamma_ic & bow. Added mu which is another two dimensional matrix to show usage of n.

Comment: Do `c` and `z` iterate through all possible indices for `gamma_ic` and `bow` respectively? I think it is worth showing how they iterate, and how you are using `n`. Also any thoughts or understanding you have about vectorisation (it may be easy or hard to vectorise your code, but it would be good to understand what is blocking you and try to fix that)

Comment: If you share the loop codes for `c` and `z`, we might be able to help to get rid of those loops too. But for the given code, you could try out - `n = sum(gamma_ic(1:number_documents,c).*bow(1:number_documents,z))`

Comment: I have updated the code with relevant portions of the outer loops.

Comment: What exactly or how exactly are you getting `maxNumber` and `K`?

Comment: maxNumber and K are constants being passed on to the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you to get `mu`, which seems to be the desired output -

```
mu = bow(1:number_documents,1:maxNumber).'*gamma_ic(1:number_documents,1:K)./2.3
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused here, will the dimensions agree to perform element wise operation? Note that `K` may not be equal to `maxNumber`. Edit: got it, that's why you are taking the transpose I suppose? Ignored it initially