# Matlab Element-wise Matrix Multiplication

Tags: matlab

In an effort to reduce usage of loops in my Matlab code, I'm trying to use elementwise multiplication to compute matrix values. Following is the code I initially had

```
for doc = 1:docs 
    for word = 1:words
        den =0;
        for topic = 1:topics
            posterior(topic,doc,word) =prior(1,topic)*expDoc(doc,topic)*expWord(word,topic);
            den  = den + posterior(topic,doc,word) ;
        end     
    end
end
```

With reference to a [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26598046/vectorizing-arithmetic-operations) question. Following is my attempt

```
 posterior(1:topics,1:docs,1:words) = prior(1,1:topics).*expDoc(1:docs,1:topics).*expWord(1:words,1:topics);
 den = sum(posterior(:,:,:));
 posterior(:,:,:)  =  posterior(:,:,:)/(den);
```

However, as required for elementwise operations, how do I ensure that the multiplcation is done with matrices of same dimensions?

Comment: Your attempt wont work, because `prior`, `expDoc` and `expWord` are all 2D arrays, so you can't use element-wise multiplication to get a 3D array. Think carefully about what is being multiplied together.

Comment: Ok, so how would you go about optimizing the for loops?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to get this to work through careful use of `bsxfun` and `permute`. `permute` is used to rearrange the order of the dimensions of a matrix - we'll use this to rearrange your variables to get them in the right order to multiply them using `bsxfun`.

From what I can tell, you have three variables:

```
prior, size == [1,topics];
expDoc, size == [docs,topics];
expWord, size == [words,topics];
```

and you want to get a final variable:

```
posterior, size == [topics,docs,words]
```

I *think* you should be able to get the matrix `posterior` by using the following method:

```
prior_perm = prior.';
expDoc_perm = expDoc.';
expWord_perm = permute(expWord,[2,3,1]);

posterior = bsxfun(@times,prior_perm,bsxfun(@times,expDoc_perm,expWord_perm));

den = sum(posterior(:));
```

You will want to make sure to test this produces the right output though, as I haven't.

Comment: Those `permute( ..[2 1])` could be replaced by `transposes` and those must be cheaper. Otherwise good solution! +1

Comment: @Divakar ah yes, true. I was so caught up in the overall solution, I missed that. Cheers!